# User selected path

Tags: c#, string, path, filedialog

I have a program that reads and writes to a text file. The program creates the file if it doesn't exist. Currently I have a predefined path and name to store the file. How do I allow a user to name, and select where they want to store it, and then apply it to all areas in the program where it's being used?

I don't have a coding issue as of yet, I just need to direction on how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: You can use a SaveFileDialog to save the file, this however wont help with knowing where it was put.  For that you have to store that information somewhere, I would suggest in a DB with references to the userID and docID

Comment: Or pass the file and location parameters to Main() if it's a console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SaveFileDialog`. Like this

```
SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog;
if (ofd.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Replace oldpath with the variable you used to store the path before.
    oldpath = ofd.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a WinForms Application?

If yes, use SaveFileDialog Button

Kind regards
Steve

Comment: A better answer would be one that shows the use of `SaveFileDialog` :)

Comment: Thanks for your help